# strtoull with base 36 overflowing unsigned long long on Linux 32bit

Tags: c++, c, linux, integer

Anyone know why using strtoull will overlow an unsigned long long? The value of "x" is 12 when I make the call, so I'm trying to convert a 12 digit base 36 num to unsigned long long.

This should work right? It doesn't matter whether I compile 32 or 64bit. I'm using g++ on redhat.

buffer is a char*

```
char *strPtr = buffer + ORDERIDOFFSET;
char *endPtr = strPtr + ORDERIDLENGTH;
long x = long((endPtr)) - long(buffer + ORDERIDOFFSET);
unsigned long long orderid = strtoull((buffer + ORDERIDOFFSET), &(endPtr), 36);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be under the misapprehension that `endptr` is an input parameter to `strtoull`, which tells it how long the input string is. It is not. It is an output parameter, which `strtoull` uses to tell you the first character it could not convert.

I presume that your buffer is not nul-terminated; probably there is an alphanumeric character following your 12-digit base-36 number.

By the way, imho, `x` would be better computed as `endPtr - strPtr`. Casting to `long` is not really correct.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to use `endPtr` as an input parameter.  `std::strtoull` takes the second parameter as an **output** parameter.

You may find it more robust to use `std::stoull` instead of `std::strtoull`:

```
char *strPtr = buffer + ORDERIDOFFSET;
char *endPtr = strPtr + ORDERIDLENGTH; // assuming ORDERIDLENGTH takes you 1 passed the end of the actual ID string
std::string s(strPtr, endPtr);
unsigned long long orderid = std::stoull(s, nullptr, 36);
```

Additionally,

```
long x = long((endPtr)) - long(buffer + ORDERIDOFFSET);
```

is not portable to 64-bit systems (you would truncate the address).  I'm pretty sure you want

```
std::size_t x = endPtr - strPtr;
```